# Grep that shows the pattern line and the matching line

Tags: bash, grep, cygwin

Suppose I have these two files:

1.

```
Locus_1 univ
Locus_2 anc
Locus_3 cat
```

2.

```
university  GO:000001
impromptu   GO:000002
advanced    GO:000003
inheritance GO:000004
```

I want to do a grep -f of the $2 of file #1 on file #2, but I also want to retrieve the lines of the first file and the whole line of file #2 that match $2 of file #1.

Basically, I want my output to be like this

```
Locus_1 univ university GO:000001
Locus_2 anc  advanced   GO:000003
```

How can I do this?
I thought I could parse the first file line by line with a `for` cycle and then store the line in a variable, but I was not able to succeed.

I use a Cygwin shell for Windows.

Comment: Can you use `awk`?

Comment: @MichaelVehrs: yes, Cygwin is intended to be more or less like a Linux shell, so I can use it, as well as `sed` etc.

Comment: Are the values unique in any of the columns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save this to a file, let's say `patterns.awk`, then call `awk -f patterns.awk patterns data`, where `patterns` is your first file, and `data` the second:

```
NR == FNR {
    prefix[NR] = $0;
    pattern[NR] = $2;
    count++;
    next;
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        if (index($1, pattern[i]) > 0) {
            print prefix[i] " " $0;
            next;
        }
    }
}
```

This works as follows: The first rule is used while we are reading the pattern file, i.e. while the total number of records equals the number of records in the file. It saves the line and the pattern to search for in two arrays and continues. The second rule is used as soon as the total number of records exceeds the number of records in the file, i.e. while we are reading the data file. It checks whether any of the patterns matches the first column of the line. If so, it prints the matching line from the pattern file, and then the matching line from the data file.

Comment: Great! That did perfectly! Can you explain me in detail what does this script do?